# Gradle - generate pom without dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, pom.xml

I want to generate a pom file that does not include dependencies. I have tried clearing the dependencies using the code below, however the dependencies are still listed in the generated pom.

```
install.doFirst {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.dependencies.clear()
    }
}
```

**Why I need this:** I need a pom file to be included with my jar when I upload it to a "home brewed" service, however the service blows up when it reads '+' as the version for the dependencies (I am using dynamic dependencies).

Comment: Have you tried clearing the configurations instead?

Comment: @JoshGagnon how would I do that?

Comment: I have no idea if it would work (hence a mere comment) but `configurations.compile.clear()` is probably worth a shot, although it sounds super hacky. You probably are betting off reading section 65.2.4 here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html and trying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the solution below calling `gradle cleanPom`. Basically I use an XML parser to edit the generated POM.

```groovy
apply plugin: 'maven'

pomFileLocation="build/poms/noDeps.pom"

/**
 * Creates pom with dependencies
 */
task writeNewPom << {
    pom {}.writeTo(pomFileLocation)
}

/**
 * Reads and Overwrites POM file removing dependencies
 */
task cleanPom(dependsOn: writeNewPom) << {
    def xml = new XmlParser().parse(pomFileLocation)
    def nodes = []
    xml.dependencies[0].each {
        nodes.add(it)
    }
    def parrent = nodes.first().parent()
    nodes.each {
        parrent.remove(it)
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(pomFileLocation))).print(xml)
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            // Do not write any dependencies into the POM
            pom*.whenConfigured { pom -> pom.dependencies.clear() }                 
        }
    }
}
```